# How to select a from date and End date from DateTimePicker...I have a following code

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using `DateTimePicker` control and the following code which shows a present `DateTime` when I select it from the picker. I need that whatever `DateTime` I've selected it'll shows that only, not the present.

I am displaying it on the next page...

```
DateTime DateFrom = DateTime.Now;
DateTime DateTo = DateTime.now;

DateTime.TryParse(datetimepicker.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out DateFrom);
DateTime.TryParse(datetimepicker.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out DateTo);
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? i'm afraid the question isn't very clear

Comment: Are you saying you want to select a date range with the `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: Actually i m displaying the date&time on the next page. The date&time i select is present because of "DateTime.now", what code should  i write their that it will displays a date&time whatever i select from datetimepicker control.

Comment: For a start, tryparse is for turning strings into dates, as `DateTimePicker.Value` already is a date this entire code fragment is meaningless

Comment: @oldBoyCoder...yes yes...range between

Comment: Thank you and appreciated for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is very unclear but it is clear that your not very familiar with how .net works

so here are a few examples that might highlight what you are misunderstanding

how to set the date of a picker

`datetimepicker.Value = yourDateTime`

how to get the date from a picker

`yourDateTime = datetimepicker.Value`

how to set the date range that is valid for selection

```
datetimepicker.MaxDate = yourMaxDate;
datetimepicker.MinDate = yourMinDate;
```

how to turn a string into a date

```
DateTime tmp;
if(DateTime.TryParse(yourString, out tmp))
yourdatetime =  tmp
```

How to display a non editable date

`label.Text = yourDateTime.ToShortDateString()`

how to select a date range, either use 2 DateTimePickers or a MonthCalendar

How to remove a Timezone from the date

`yourUTCDate = yourDate.ToUniversalTime()`

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
DateTime DateFrom = DateTime.Now;
DateTime DateTo = DateTime.Now;

DateTime.TryParse(datetimepicker1.Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out DateFrom);
DateTime.TryParse(datetimepicker2.Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out DateTo);
```

Comment: Thank you vaibhav...actually i did  a mistake that given a same to both datetimepicker. thanx to show me that.

Comment: Thank you and appreciated for the help.

Comment: Hi Deepak,
I have tried to show you the same but it is not clear in your question that what is your actual problem.
Its ok, at last problem has resolved, that's good.

Comment: Hi Mike,

You have forgot here that he wants to adjust the time to universal that's why we have to do this.

Comment: @VaibhavMishra thats what the ToUniversalTime() method is for